# Is there a comprehensive geocoding DB available?

Tags: data-request, geocoding, database

Ideally I want a database that contains all points on the earth down to about 3m by 3m square and a corresponding street address if one exists (might be a many to one relationship).

Does such a DB exist, and, if so, which is the most comprehensive?

Comment: Surely this *must* be  a duplicate. [Take your pick](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=geocoding+database)

Answer (score 3):

[Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Overview/) has an API that gives data on at the very least the street level. You can provide a latitude and longitude and have an address returned.

Comment: Looks good, thanks. Wonder if they will mind me doing a few billion queries ;)

Comment: You can spin up your own instance: http://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Installation/

Answer (score 1):

Also try out [Who's On First (WOF)](https://whosonfirst.org/):

> A gazeteer or big list of places, each with a stable identifier and some number of descriptive properties about that location. (https://whosonfirst.org/what/)